# How to remove a linestring which is added part by part to GE in one go?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am trying to draw a road incrementally as an animation over GE plugin. I have a set of coordinates (lat,long) in an array and I am using the following function in a loop at  small time intervals to draw the entire road in small parts animatedly.

```
var intFeatureCounter4Trace=0  
  function createPath(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2,strToolType){
        lineStringPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
        var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
        lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
        lineString.setTessellate(true);
        lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat1,lng1,0);
        lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat2,lng2,0);
        lineStringPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
        var lineStyle=lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
        lineStyle.setWidth(5);
        lineStyle.getColor().set("9900FFFF"); //'aabbggrr' format
        intFeatureCounter4Trace+=1;
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);
    }
```

While drawing the road in small parts I am keeping track of the number of small line segments that are added to the GE plugin and use this feature count to remove all the added line segements in a loop using the following function :-

```
function clearPath(){
    for(var i=0;i<intFeatureCounter4Trace;i++){
       ge.getFeatures().removeChild(ge.getFeatures().getLastChild());
    }
}
```

The problem is for a large number of (lat,longs) say 20,000 or so, the `clearPath()` function hangs the browser and sometimes some features that are not to be removed are also removed. Is there a way to remove all the smaller segments in one go? i.e, Is there a way to append all smaller segments part by part (as animation) to a single feature and then remove it in one go from the GE plugin DOM instead of removing it part by part?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.

Firstly, using the existing code you have simply wrap any call to your `clearPath` method using the [google.earth.executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739) function. This should stop the hanging and execute the api calls much faster.

```
google.earth.executeBatch(ge, clearPath);
```

Secondly, you could simply write a cleaner `clearPath` function to remove all the features without the need for a global index.

```
function clearPath() {
  var features = ge.getFeatures();
  while (features.getFirstChild()) {
    features.removeChild(features.getFirstChild());
  }
}
```

Thirdly, the way I would approach it, is to alter your `createPath` to simply create a single linestring placemark. Then I would create a `amendPath` method that will update the coordinate data for that placemark. Finally I would alter the `clearPath` method to simply call clear on the linestring coordinate array. You could also add a `removePath` method too if desired...

Although it is written here and untested something along the following lines should work.

```
var path = null; // global reference to the placemark we will create

// set up the path placemark
function createPath() {
  path = ge.createPlacemark('');
  path.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));

  var line = ge.createLineString('');
  line.setTessellate(true);

  var style = path.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
  style.setWidth(5);
  style.getColor().set("9900FFFF");

  path.setGeometry(line);
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(path);
}

// update the path placemark's coordinate geometry
function ammendPath(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2) {
  var line = path.getGeometry();
  line.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat1,lng1,0);
  line.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat2,lng2,0);
  path.setGeometry(line);
}

// clear the path placemark's coordinate geometry 
function clearPath() {
  path.getGeometry().getCoordinates().clear();
}

// remove the path placemark entirely (if required...)
function removePath() {
  ge.getFeatures().removeChild(path);
}
```

Comment: Hello Fraser, Thanx for the above suggestions. The fist suggestion though did not help me with this query, but came to know of it & using it in other tasks. The last suggestion did the trick, this was exactly what I was looking for and now I am able to clear the entire line placemark drawn part by part at on go. Thanx once again. Regards,Shiva

Comment: Hello Fraser, I have one more query regarding this, while creating the path I have to do so in parts, i.e I have a series of lat,longs differentiated by part numbers. When I get a new part number I have to start drawing the path with a gap between the previous drawn path & current line/path, and so on till the end. Is it possible to do so with the last 'createPath & amendPath' suggestion given by you? Regards,Shiva

Comment: Sure, just amend the createPath function to accept an id parameter, then generate a unique path for each segment. I would probably hold these segments in a global array. You could then alter the amendPath function to accept an id, or index, so that you can amend the correct path. If you are having problems with it let me know and I will edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: Hi Fraser, Before u had replied back I tried out a similar approach, declared a global array of path objects and ran the code within the createPath function within a for loop for the required number of separate paths using the JS's eval function, as I am working on an ajax app & required dynamic variable declaration. Then used the amendPath to push coordinates for the individual path segments. While clearing I run the for-loop on the global array of paths & remove the paths from GE plugin using the same clearPath function.This approach is working right. What are ur thoughts? Regards, Shiva